# Flexbox: How to make images equal height in flex items?

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

Okay, so I'm trying to display images with equal width and height inside 6 flexbox items.

In screen size with `min-width: 768px` each flex-item grows to 1 when there is 30% space, i.e. *flex: 1 30%;* *flex-direction: is changed to row;*

**The** **problem**: The flex item divs themselves are equal in height and width but the image inside each flex item are various sizes.

**Attempt**: Tried align-items: stretch; and even giving min-height to each image doesn't work?

**Also is flex-wrap even necessary when using flex: 1 30%?**

I'm clearly doing something wrong, any ideas?

```css
/* ## Services */
.services-wrap {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 4rem;
}

.services-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.service-img {
  min-height: 100% !important;
  /*width: 100%;*/
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .services-flex {
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 0 4rem;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .flex-box {
    flex: 1 30%;
    /*margin: 1rem;*/
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="services-wrap">
  <h3>OUR SERVICE</h3>
  <hr>
  <div class="services-flex">
    <div id="service-box" class="flex-box">
      <img class="service-img" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/service-img/comercial.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="service-box" class="flex-box">
      <img class="service-img" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/service-img/residential.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="service-box" class="flex-box">
      <img class="service-img" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/service-img/rural.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="service-box" class="flex-box">
      <img class="service-img" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/service-img/industrial.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="service-box" class="flex-box">
      <img class="service-img" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/service-img/other.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="service-box" class="flex-box">
      <img class="service-img" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/service-img/other.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**UPDATE**

Okay I think the issue was that 2 of the 6 image sizes were to small like 200 by 250 vs the rest which was 600-1200px. So I've fixed this by having larger image sizes initial so the image is not distorted and also grows in equal.

Notice the first and the last image heights are not equal, but why?

***Please check the CSS again as I have updated it with the changes to match the image above!***

Please help, thank you!

Comment: In screen width's from 768px they have to me the same height and width **per row**, so how is that wrong?

Comment: img {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 0;
} Set a fixed width & height for img and they will maintain that width and height for any image.

Comment: @HarshitDamani That will distort an image with a different aspect ratio.

Comment: @LGSon As it has been mentioned in the post, they did try to make the images of same size by "stretching" and what not. So, I don't know if they would mind that.

Comment: And yes, you need `flex-wrap: wrap`, or else all will stay in 1 line

Comment: And I don't know if you need to make use of the "id" attribute, but they need to be unique for every div element.

Comment: Yes, will fix the ids. Still not understand how / why the images are not taking the full width of the flex item

Comment: if you add a _working_ code snippet, with the different sized images, we will be able to provide a proper answer.

Comment: @Shaz The answer to _"Still not understand how / why the images are not taking the full width"_ is, use `width: 100%` on the `img`

Comment: @Shaz This is the outcome if heights are different using `width: 100%`: https://jsfiddle.net/dtu86gwx/ ... and this if they have equal aspect ratio: https://jsfiddle.net/dtu86gwx/1/

Comment: It's funny how the answer has been rated down when it does provide the alternatives to solving it unlike what has been mentioned that the aspect ratio aren't equal, if they were the problem won't arise in the first place. Either if they take 100% height or 100% width inside the parent div, it won't matter since the outcome will be the same. But, that's the issue here, the aspect ratio aren't equal.

Comment: You have to compromise one thing with the other for this issue, either crop the image maintaining its aspect ratio and filling out the parent div, or distorting the aspect ratio by setting it to fixed values.

Comment: @HarshitDamani Since we can't see the original images, any answer will be a guess...and at SO we don't want guessed answers, we want _proper_ questions so we can give _proper_ answers.

Comment: Yeah, but regardless of the original images. If the issue is what we have been discussing, there's only 2 ways to go about it. And if the issue isn't aspect ratio, then there's no issue at all.

Comment: @Shaz The Question lacks to sufficiently specify the desired outcome and problems. Can you edit in a clarification please?

Comment: Please check the update! Appreciate the feedback

Comment: @Shaz We can't debug a screen dump. Provide a working code snippet reproducing the issue, with the original images, or else we have no chance to detect want went wrong.

Comment: HERE is the link: http://radian3.com/, ideas please?

Comment: @Shaz What browser do you use? ... It works for me in Chrome/Firefox/Edge/IE

Comment: So the gap whitespace for 1st and last image. Using Chrome as well

Comment: @Shaz Also, make sure you refreshed/cleared your cache

Comment: Thank although I had cleared cache and was using incognito, Working now. So I guess the problem was not having big pictures to start off. Omg. Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 1):

I've used this css `min-height:100%;` for smaller images to expand to parent `flex-box` items. I've also hardcoded `min-height: 220px;` to parent items just to have all equal height.. see the snippet in full screen to see how it works..

```css
/* ## Services */

.services-wrap {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 4rem;
}

.services-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .services-flex {
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 0 4rem;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    max-width: 1500px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .flex-box {
    flex: 1 30%;
    margin: 1rem;
    min-height: 220px;
  }
}

img {
  min-height: 100%!important;
}
```

```html
<section class="services-wrap">
  <h3>OUR SERVICE</h3>
  <hr>
  <div class="services-flex">
    <div id="service-box" class="flex-box">
      <img class="service-img" src="http://placehold.it/125">
    </div>
    <div id="service-box" class="flex-box">
      <img class="service-img" src="http://placehold.it/155">
    </div>
    <div id="service-box" class="flex-box">
      <img class="service-img" src="http://placehold.it/175">
    </div>
    <div id="service-box" class="flex-box">
      <img class="service-img" src="http://placehold.it/195">
    </div>
    <div id="service-box" class="flex-box">
      <img class="service-img" src="http://placehold.it/205">
    </div>
    <div id="service-box" class="flex-box">
      <img class="service-img" src="http://placehold.it/225">
    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Pretty sure the images look fine right now because each of them has a equal side. But if the height:width ratio isn't the same of any 2 images, the image will get distorted. And if you avoid distorting it, then it won't fill the entire area of its parent div element.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a technical problem, this is conceptual problem.
When you have images of varying aspect ratios and you want to display them in an orderly, even mannor, then first you have to think whether you want:

a) the images to be distorted or trunctated to leave no whitespace

or

b) the images to have whitespace between them or around them. In this case you can also make decisions on how you want to distribute the whitespaces.

Those are your basic choices.

For a) you can set the images width to 100% or the image wrapper to overflow-y: hidden

For b) you can set max-width and max-height and and center your images in the wrappers with centering method of your choice.

As a bonus possibility you can also set the flex-basis to auto and flex-grow to 0 and let the flex-box decide how many images are displayed before the row-wrap. On large 4k displays you might not want two rows of enlarged images anyways

Answer (score 0):

Could you try setting the image as a background image inside the flex div?  As then you can do: background-size:cover;  This will ensure all the div is covered by the image, although some of it may be missing depending on its proportions in comparison to the div. If you still want the alt tag you could try adding a transparent png placeholder inside the div which can contain the alt text.

Comment: Since the main focus of an image is usually in the center you can always add `background-position:center center;` so only the sides get cropped.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for your problem if you don't want the images to get distorted but rather if you would have them cropped in position just to fill the div containing it inside the flexbox.

```
.flex-box{
  height:200px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

img {
    width: 300px;
    border: 0;
}
```

This sets the height of the parent container as fixed and hides if the image overflows. And the image maintains a fixed width inside the parent div.

If not, your other alternative is as I mentioned in the comment is to set the width and height for the image to a fixed value.

Comment: With this solution the images will look like miniatures on a 1920px wide screen.

Comment: Those "dimensions" just give the idea of how to fix the image and parent div size, there's nowhere that it has been mentioned that the values need to be 200 and 300px respectively. And depending on the screen size, @media queries can be implemented to tweak it around.